# How to change an images size in c++, SDL

Tags: c++, image, sdl

How can I change the images size in the code below:

```
const int XHome = 10, YHome = 10;
const int WHome = 50, HHome = 50;
.
.
.

SDL_Surface* Image = SDL_LoadBMP(Address);

SDL_Rect destRect;

destRect.x = WHome * x; 
destRect.y = HHome * y; 
destRect.w = WHome;
destRect.h = HHome;

SDL_BlitSurface(Image, NULL, mainScreen, &destRect);

SDL_FreeSurface(Image);
```

When I put `Image` in `mainScreen` which is another `SDL_Surface`, It's bigger than 50*50. Is it possible to resize `Image`? Thank you.

---

this is what happens when I set the WHome and HHome, 50*50.
Since I have only 5 reputation, I can't post images. To see the image please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCQJq.png).

But when I set them like the original images size, this is what I see:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QifU5.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger"? What size is it rendering at? Your destination rectangle should specify the size; it seems right. Have you tried changing WHome and HHome? By the way, if you're using SDL2 you should use an SDL_Texture for your image instead of a surface. You'll get hardware acceleration and you can specify the destination size just like you can with blitting, when you render via [SDL_RenderCopy](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy).

Comment: I thought it will resize the image. But it didn't. I will Set The Image soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SDL_BlitSurface documentation:

> Only the position is used in the dstrect (the width and height are ignored).

I highly recommend switching to SDL 2 for many reasons (hardware acceleration being a big one); this task would also become trivial with a texture and [SDL_RenderCopy](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy). If you're somehow stuck using SDL 1, you can either look into scaling surfaces manually, or use a library like [SDL_gfx](http://cms.ferzkopp.net/index.php/software/13-sdl-gfx), which has custom blit functions.

Comment: I have to work with SDL 1 So I used SDL_gfx. Thanks for your help.